# How to use a counter inside node<> in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters

I'm trying to draw nodes one by one on a list of predefined coordinates.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
   \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]           
       \coordinate (a) at (1,4);
       \coordinate (b) at (1,5);
       \coordinate (c) at (1,6);
       \coordinate (d) at (1,7);

       \newcounter{count}
       \setcounter{count}{1}
       \foreach \name in {a,b,c,d}
       {
          \node<\the\value{count}->[circle,inner sep=0pt] at (\name) {$$};
          \stepcounter{count}
       }      
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I've the above MWE, which I'd figured after looking at some other answers on TeX.SE, but I'm confounded by the error message generated by LaTeX:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@count already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean something like `\node[circle,inner sep=0pt] at (\name) {$\thecount$};`?

Comment: Nope, I meant node<i-> {a node at point a[i]}...

Comment: @TCSGrad: `\node<i->{...};` doesn't look like a correct syntax in the `article` class, although you can use `<i->` with TikZ commands to give overlay specifications in the `beamer` class. What coordinates are you trying to refer to with the counter values?

Comment: @KevinC - Oops, its in beamer that I'm trying to do this, sorry for the wrong MWE (that i copied from one of my other questions in article class)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a foreach loop you can use the on purpose `count` key to count the items in the list: no need to define other counters.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]           
       \coordinate (a) at (1,4);
       \coordinate (b) at (1,5);
       \coordinate (c) at (1,6);
       \coordinate (d) at (1,7);

       \foreach \name[count=\mycount from 1] in {a,b,c,d}
       {
          \node<\mycount->[draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] at (\name) {$ $};
       }      
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `count` key starts counting from 1, but you can customize the initial value with the help of `from=<initial value>`. Furthermore, you can also avoid to define at first all the coordinates:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
       \foreach \pos[count=\mycount] in {{(1,4)},{(1,5)},{(1,6)},{(1,7)}}
       {
          \node<\mycount->[draw,circle,inner sep=0pt] at \pos {$ $};
       }      
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @TCSGrad: you're welcome :)